# Change Text of Create an Account in Login Block

Tags: 7, theming

I want to change text of **Create an account** to

```
<div>something></div><span><a href="actual_link">Click here</a></span/>
```

When I print the form I got these values

```
[links] => Array
        (
            [#markup] => <ul><li class="first"><a href="/user/register" title="Create a new user account.">Create new account</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="/user/password" title="Request new password via e-mail.">Forgot your password?</a></li>
</ul>
        )
```

Also, I gave a try in `settings.php` like

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  '"Create a new user account' => ' <div>somethifn></div><span><a href="actula link>Click here</a></span/>',
);
```

But this prints as a text.

Anybody can help?

Comment: why you dont try achieve it with jquery ?

Comment: Can you give the debug code of the form? (how you debug it? you say that the code is in settings.php??)

Comment: As I understand you don't try to edit the login form, but the tab-menu of the login form.

Comment: Hint: The string you are trying to replace is `"Create a new user account`, but Drupal uses `Create a new user account`.

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned problem can be easily solved by using hook_form_alter [hook_form_alterhook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) . You can use that function in our template.php of your custom theme .

In template.php write..

```
function custom_theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if( $form['form_id']['#value'] === 'user_register_form'){// For registration form on 'user/register' page
    $form['actions']['submit']['#prefix'] = '<div class="test">';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = '--your text--';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  }
  if( $form['#id'] === 'user-login-form' ){  // For login block that comes with drupal core blocks and can be assigned to any region. 
    $form['links']['#markup'] = '<div class="item-list"><ul><li class="first"><a href="user/register" title="--your text--">--your text--</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="/user/password" title="Request new password via e-mail.">Request new password</a></li>
</ul></div>';
  }
}
```

This will change your text from 'Create a new account' to your custom text. And don't forget to clear the cache :).

Reply on this thread if you still find some problem.

Answer (score 0):

So lets assume you want to alter the tab-menu of the `/user` page.

First the `dpm()` doesn't work because you are logged out.

Then you must create a module, but if you are too lazy paste the code on the `template.php` of your theme and rename `module` with your theme's name.

Then debug the menu:

```
function module_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  debug($data);
}
```

After you find the `title` you want to edit your function:

```
function module_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  // The path of the array
  debug($data['tabs'][0]['output'][0]['#link']['title']);
  // Edit the actual array value
  $data['tabs'][0]['output'][0]['#link']['title'] = "My new title";
}
```

If you want to edit something in the login form:

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
    debug($form);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have solved the same problem with just two lines at the top in my `page.tpl.php` file,

```
<?php if($title == 'Create an account'):$title='whatever title you want';endif;  ?>
```

You can also include html tags to modify the title.

Thank you.

Comment: The user doesn't want to change any page title, but the text shown for a link.

Comment: Then it will be better to use l().
As mentioned here :
https://api.drupal.org/comment/13259#comment-13259